# menu callback in not called

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want to add a couple of buttons - "settings" and "restart" to my scene, placed above everything. I do the below [in my init()]:

```
auto settingsMenu = MenuItemImage::create("settings_gold@2x.png", "settings_white@2x.png",
CC_CALLBACK_1(GameLevelLayer::settingsButtonTapped, this));
settingsMenu->setPosition(Point(440, 280));
this->addChild(settingsMenu);
```

I also add touch handler to process game "actions," as below:

```
// handle user touches
auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLevelLayer::onTouchBegan, this);
listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLevelLayer::onTouchEnded, this);
dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

My onTouchBegan() and onTouchEnded() are called fine, but settingsButtonTapped() is never called, as touch handler apparently swallows everything.

How should this be processed in cocos2d-x 3.x, so that clicking on the menu calls settingsButtonTapped()?

Thank you

Comment: can you add the code of your onTouchBegan method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague advised that the cocos2d-x 3.x way is to use ui:Button, instead of MenuItemImage.

Changed the code to be:

```
auto settingsButton = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
settingsButton->setTouchEnabled(true);
settingsButton->loadTextures("settings_gold@2x.png", "settings_white@2x.png");
settingsButton->setPosition(Point(440, 270));
settingsButton->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLevelLayer::settingsButtonTapped, this));
this->addChild(settingsButton);

// handle user touches
auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLevelLayer::onTouchBegan, this);
listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLevelLayer::onTouchEnded, this);
dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

Now, pressing a button calls the button callback, and touches on the layer are still processed as they were.